# rewriting to always use www in domain ( even on subpages )

Tags: .htaccess, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I've added the following to my .htaccess to properly redirect any visitors from http://domain.com to http://www.domain.com ... but I still can't get it to work with subpages...ie http://domain.com/subpage is not yet redirecting to http://www.domain.com/subpage .

Here is what I have in my htaccess now:

```
<Files wp-config.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R]


</IfModule>
```

So the question is what else would I need to add or update in my htaccess to get this working?

Many thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You have the redirect happening *after* you've done routing to `index.php`, it needs to happen before any routing rules get executed. Try swapping them around:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

(also added the `[NC]` flag so case isn't checked in hostname match)